# How to get the date of oldest order that user ordered?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need

To bring the followers of one merchant

Then brings the date of following

Then check if the user have orders from this merchant bring first order date that user ordered from the merchant!

my shut:

```
SELECT
    `users`.`id`,
    `users`.`name`,
    `users`.`avatar`,
    merchant_user.created_at AS follow_date,
    MIN(orders.created_at) AS first_order_date
FROM
    `users`
    LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `merchant_user` ON `users`.`id` = `merchant_user`.`user_id`
WHERE
    merchant_user.merchant_id = 1
WHERE
    orders.status = 'approved'
GROUP BY
    `users`.`id`;
```

Comment: does your updated query not do what you want?  if so, explain how.  sample data, current results, and desired results is very helpful

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All columns in Select which dont have aggregate function should be part of group by clause.

```
SELECT
        `users`.`id`,
        `users`.`name`,
        `users`.`avatar`,
        merchant_user.created_at AS follow_date,
        MIN(orders.created_at) AS first_order_date
    FROM
        `users`
        LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id`
        LEFT JOIN `merchant_user` ON `users`.`id` = `merchant_user`.`user_id`
    WHERE
        merchant_user.merchant_id = 1
    and
        orders.status = 'approved'
    GROUP BY
        `users`.`id`,
        `users`.`name`,
        `users`.`avatar`,
        merchant_user.created_at;
```

Comment: We cant use two where clause, conditions should be added using AND/OR.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You want aggregation:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, MIN(o.created_at) AS first_order_date
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON u.id = o.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name;
```

Note that I also introduced table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: can you pls explain the query?

Comment: @jean . . . This is a pretty basic aggregation query with a `JOIN`, so I'm not sure what you don't understand.

Comment: I updated the question pls check it! What if I need to use where with multi join?

Comment: @jean . . . I don't generally revise answers for significant changes to questions.  I don't treat this as a game of "guess the question".  The proper thing to do is to ask a new question.

Comment: Then pls remove your answer I'll remove mine and ask again with more detail with thankful!